# How to access an attribute of a dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get data stored in attributes of dynamically created elements that have been added to the DOM.

When a button is clicked, an AJAX call is made which returns a collection of objects. Using Javascript/JQuery, I am then adding new HTML elements for each of these returned objects, and adding their property values to attributes on the element. I am then adding a click listener to each of these dynamically created elements. When clicked I want to get the value in these attributes.

At the moment the `id` value is present, but the value of `name` is `undefined`.

For example, given the following HTML:

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Get objects" />
<div id="objects-wrapper"></div>
```

Json response from server:

```
[
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "eeeee",
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "MIT Top New"
  }
]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var posting = $.post('/get/objects', {
      id: id
    });

    posting.done(function(data) {
      var objectsWrapper = $('#objects-wrapper');
      objectsWrapper.empty();

      if (data.length == 0) {
        $(objectsWrapper).html('No objects found...');
      } else {
        $(objectsWrapper).empty();
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var object = $('<div class="object"><a href="#" name="' + data[i].name + '" class="object-link" id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</a></div>').on('click', function() {
            var objectId = $(this).attr('id'); // <-- is present
            var name = $(this).attr('name'); // <-- undefined

            // do something with name
          });
          objectsWrapper.append(object);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

The `name` value is present and is being used as the anchor text. Which I have verified as the following markup:

```
<a href="#" name="MIT Top New" description="MIT Top News" class="object-link" id="17">MIT Top New</a>
```

How do I correctly get at the attribute `name` of the dynamically created anchor element?

Comment: Did you try to move it out of function?

Comment: $(this).attr('id');

This does not find anything. It's pointing to an object that inside has a that has that id. Use find to fins a inside .

Comment: To add to what @DanteTheSmith said, if you add the `a` to the `div` with `append()`, or similar, it should work, if you only want the click to be handled by the anchor and not the `div` too.

Comment: var name =  $(object).find("a").attr("name")   this will do. You are trying with this keyword. Try using the object variable itself

Comment: @patilprashant6792 This worked `$(this).find('a').attr('name');`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` of jQuery to find for the elements with selector in the DOM and make it work

Here is an example with your data.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "eeeee",
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "MIT Top New"
  }
];
data.forEach(e=>{
$("#objects-wrapper").append(`  </br> <a href="#" name="${e.name}"> ${e.name} </a> </br>`)
});

$("#button").click(function(){
   
  
   $("#objects-wrapper").find("a").each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("name"))
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Get objects" />
<div id="objects-wrapper"></div>
```

By the way in your code, why you need to get it from DOM ? you're assigning the name yourself why not use it ? `data[i].name` this is the name right. Use it instead of getting from the DOM again